# How to specify field specifier in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am storing user data in `Meteor.users.profile`, but I am having trouble retrieving them via the return command.

Code looks like this:

```
Template.details.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
        var name = event.target.nam.value;
        var age = event.target.nombor.value;
        // var gender = event.target.sex.value; 
        // var gen = Meteor.user().profile.gender;

        Meteor.users.update({
            _id: currentUser
        }, {
            $set: {
                "profile.name": name,
                "profile.age": age
            }
        });
        Router.go('/tryy');
    }
});
Template.tryy.helpers({
    'people': function() {
        //var gender = Meteor.user().profile.gender;
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            gender: "gender"
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="tryy">
  <ul>  
      {{#each people}}
          <li><a href="#"> {{name}} {{age}}  </a></li> 
      {{/each}} 
 </ul>
</template>
```

What is wrong with this: `return Meteor.users.find({}, {gender: "gender"});`?

I want to see list of gender opposite to `currentUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm...... I have answer your another question yet

At first, you should deal with the situation when there is no login user in your helpers:

```
Template.tryy.helpers({
    'people': function() {
        // you should deal with the situation when no current user
        if (Meteor.user() === null) return null;  // or others way you like
        var gender = Meteor.user().profile.gender;
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            gender: "gender"
        });
    }
});
```

I think you should read the [Meteor document of Mongo collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) and Mongo document before asking these questions...

As you asked:
To find user whose name matched an object's **property(profile.name)**: 
`Meteor.users.find({"profile.gender": gender});`

some other useful simple query:
To find user whose name appear in an **Array(suppose it named friends):**
`Meteor.users.find({"profile.name": friends});`

If we have Alice, Bob, Cathy and friends is ['Alice', 'Cathy'], it would return Alice and Cathy

All in all, you should read these document carefully, it would help you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `find()` is the selector, the second argument is for other options. In this case, if you want to find users by their gender, you'd use the selector:

```
Meteor.users.find({"profile.gender": gender});
```

This would return all users with the specified `gender`. Please also have a look at the very detailed [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find).

Also, in your template, you should change `name` to `profile.name` (and same for age) as that's where you store these values:

```
{{#each people}}
    <li><a href="#"> {{profile.name}} {{profile.age}}  </a></li> 
{{/each}}
```